# TypeError unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when I try to plot results of linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, linear-regression

I'm trying to do some simple linear regression. I have a dataset of books with their titles, publication dates, author names, etc. I'm trying to predict the average goodreads rating of a book based on the year is was published. I used the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import seaborn as seabornInstance 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics

df = pd.read_csv('books.csv', error_bad_lines= False, warn_bad_lines = False, encoding= 'utf-8')
df.columns = ['BookID', 'Title','Authors', 'Average_Rating', 'ISBN', 'ISBN13', 'Language', 'Pages', 'Ratings_Count', 'Text_Reviews_Count', 'Publication_Date', 'Publisher']

df.drop(columns = ["ISBN", "ISBN13"], inplace = True)
df.loc[df.Language == "en-US", "Language"] = "eng"
df.loc[df.Language == "en-GB", "Language"] = "eng"
df.loc[df.Language == "en-CA", "Language"] = "eng"
df.loc[df.Language != "eng", "Language"] = "other"

temp = df["Publication_Date"].str.split("/", n = 2, expand = True)
df["Publication_Month"] = temp[1]
df["Publication_Year"] = temp[2]

X = df["Publication_Year"].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df["Average_Rating"].values.reshape(-1,1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

regressor = LinearRegression()  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(regressor.intercept_)
print(regressor.coef_)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

I had no issues until I tried to plot my predictions against the actual values on the training set. I keep getting TypeError unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'.

```
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, label = "Predictions", color='red', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(X_test, y_test, label = "Actual Values", color='blue', linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel('Year of publication')
plt.ylabel('Avg. Rating')  
plt.show()
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `X_test` is now an array and most likely has the wrong shape for plotting see marked dupe

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  Sometimes you might want to create fake data for the question - as long as it faithfully represents the actual data.. The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre].